# How to Disable Conformation Email in MailChimp?

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

I don't want to send Conformation email to my NEW subscribers. Is there any way to add them Directly to my subscriber list..without having them to click on a conformation(verification) email sent by mail chimp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant disable MailChimp's double opt-in feature if you are serving one of their proprietary subscription forms. The only way to disable the confirmation email is to create a custom subscription form that invokes the MailChimp API using the 'double_optin' => false parameter

See https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php for more details

Comment: Is it the same with all other email service providers? Or MailChimp is the only one who does this?

Comment: No, some other providers do not have the double opt in setting. 

For example EasyMail7 http://easymail7.com/ doesnt require a double opt-in list. The hybrid technology utilizes both installed and cloud components. Hybrid email systems are more cost effective in the long run, especially if you have a large mailing list